# jquery number plugin inserting as an integer into database

Tags: jquery

i've been using JQuery number plugins to help adding thousand separator in my text value, and i've been trying to insert the value as an **integer**, for example :

[image: Nett Budget]

image above is the input where i was trying to insert as a **Integer** into database.

but here is the value that being catched as a **Integer** after i convert it into integer :

```
$insert['nett_budget'] = intval($request->get('nett_budget'));
```

[image: Catched]

and here is when they are **nvchar** :

[image: nvchar]

here is the **Jquery** in index.php :

```
$('#nett_budget').number(true);
```

Is there a way to catch the whole number after the thousand separator as an **Integer** ? , or there maybe an alternate plugins that i can use, thanks!.

Comment: Use this function `function strReplace(fnd, repl, str) { return str.replace(new RegExp(fnd, 'g'), repl); }`. With this function all str will be replaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you get this value;

```
var val = "222,222";
```

As your value is in string format you should replace your unnecessary character from your value like this;

```
var finalval = val.replace(",", "");
```

Here the first parameter is the character you want to remove, and the second parameter is the empty value. Through this technique, you can get the proper integer value in string format. Convert it into an integer if you need it.

***First Modification:***
Here is the code with your code example, please check this;

set your value into a variable:

```
var _budget = $('#nett_budget').val(data.nett_budget);
```

Modify the value and replace unnecessary characters:

```
var _final_budget = _budget.replace(",", "");
```

Now use this **_final_budget** value instead of `$('#nett_budget').val(data.nett_budget);` this value. You can convert it into an integer.

Comment: sorry im really new in using these language, where should i put the var finalval ?, in my controller it was like :
`$insert['nett_budget'] = intval($request->get('nett_budget'));`,
and my index to get the value from input is : 
 `$('#nett_budget').val(data.nett_budget);`.
Thanks again.

Comment: please check the modification

Comment: thanks! it's working now, and the data is finally inputted into the databse.